# Vue: Trying to set a v-model to computed property?

Tags: vue.js

I have an initial data property that I'm using as the `v-model` for a text field.  As the default text, I want it to have the date and time formatted which I have in a computed function.  How can I have that initial data be set to the computed property at first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) for `computed` values:

```html
<input v-model="foo" />
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    updatedFoo: undefined
  };
},

computed: {
  foo: {
    get: function () {
      const defaultFoo = 'whatever the default value is';
      return this.updatedFoo ?? defaultFoo;
    },

    set: function (value) {
      this.updatedFoo = value;
    }
  }
}
```